# Metamask Rinkeby Ether Balance missing

Tags: ether, metamask, balances, ethereumj, rinkeby

I got some Rinkeby ethers from the Rinkeby faucet, after a minute or so, it showed up in my MetaMask Rinkeby network. But then after a while, my MetaMask shows 0 balance for the Rinkeby network. How did that happen?

Somehow I got some ethers in Ropsten & Kovan network but not on my Rinkeby network. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Check your address at https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/ to see if you actually have a balance. If not, it's possible that you did get it in a block, and you saw your balance in that block, but the block was then orphaned. If this balance is different than what shows in Metamask, then you'll have to go to [Metamask Support](https://support.metamask.io/home)

Edit: It sounds like the issue is because OP used the mnemonic that Truffle gives you, which is the same for everyone (since it's for running tests, which should be deterministic). WARNING: Do **not** use the mnemonic from truffle! Just look at it, all the words are sweets, so it's bad for you...

Comment: Hi MetaMask gives me a link: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57

I did not send those ethers to 0x7609F2D019Fec5b1c05051D9ADBcEdDE351B0084 

Am I getting hacked or MetaMask got hacked? Thank you

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you did now. You used the mnemonic that truffle gives you, didn't you? Since Truffle generates this for running tests, it's deterministic, and everyone gets the same mnemonic, and a lot of people have access to that address. I hope you didn't put any mainnet ether on that address.

Comment: Oh, right. You are absolutely correct. Thank you :)

Comment: why would you use Truffles mnemonic instead of metamask mnemonic?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: DO NOT USE the mnemonic that truffle gives you. Since Truffle generates this for running tests, it's deterministic, and everyone gets the same mnemonic, and a lot of people have access to that address.